# init value of component undefined

Tags: angular, initialization, custom-type

selectedProdGrp.ProductGroupNames is null because no data has been fetched yet. I defined the interface MultiLangTxtModel as a custom type but i am not sure if this was the proper approach.

i get the following error in the console:

```
NamesComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'l10n' of undefined
```

what am i doing wrong?

names.components.ts

```
 import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'field-names',
      templateUrl: './names.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./names.component.scss']
    })
    export class NamesComponent {
      @Input('disabled') editMode;
      @Input() value: MultiLangTxtModel;
      @Output() value2 = new EventEmitter<MultiLangTxtModel>();

      constructor() {
         this.value = {l10n:{de:null,en:null,fr:null,it:null}} //didnt help
      }

      onChange() {
        this.value2.emit(this.value);
      }
    }
```

names.component.html

```
        <div class="item noBottom" [ngClass]="{
      'has-danger': nameEn.invalid || nameFr.invalid || nameDe.invalid || nameIt.invalid,
      'has-success': nameEn.valid && nameFr.valid && nameDe.valid && nameIt.valid
    }">

<div class="d-flex" [ngStyle]="{'display': (lang != 'en' && lang !='*') ? 'none !important' : 'inherit'}">
  <div class="col-md-2 label" i18n="@@tables.general.name">Name {{lang}}</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 flag en"></div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" accesskey="e" id="nameEn" placeholder="Name" required alphaNumValidator [(ngModel)]="value.l10n.en" (click)="onChange()" name="nameEn" #nameEn="ngModel" [disabled]="!editMode">
    <div *ngIf="nameEn.errors && (nameEn.dirty || nameEn.touched)" class="form-control-feedback" >
      <p *ngIf="nameEn.errors.alphaNum" class="alert alert-danger"><span i18n="@@tables.general.name">c</span>&nbsp;<span i18n="@@tables.error.alphaNum">a</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

app.d.ts

```
interface MultiLangTxtModel {
    l10n: {
        de:string,
        en:string,
        fr:string,
        it:string
    }
}
```

AppComponent.component.html

```
<div class="row panel header">
  <div class="col-md-4 itemBox">
    <field-names [value]="selectedProdGrp.ProductGroupNames" (value2)="onNamesChange($event)"></field-names> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the value of `selectedProdGrp.ProductGroupNames`? Could you also print the class `AppComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get data from input inside of the constructor. Also destructuring assignment seems to be wrong. Constructor is not a part of Angular lifecycle hooks, at this moment (inside of `constructor`) input value is `undefined`, try to get it inside of `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook:

```
ngOnInit() {
  { l10n: { de: null, en: null,fr: null, it: null } } = this.value;
  console.log(l10n);
}
```

> NamesComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'l10n' of undefined

Make sure that you're using properties of `value` after it gets available in html template (`*ngIf="value"`):

```
<div class="col-md-9" *ngIf="value">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" accesskey="e" id="nameEn" placeholder="Name" required alphaNumValidator [(ngModel)]="value.l10n.en" (click)="onChange()" name="nameEn" #nameEn="ngModel" [disabled]="!editMode">
  ...
```

Comment: thanks the ngOnInit worked but now i get this error
NamesComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'has-danger: false'. Current value: 'has-danger: true'.

Comment: i can solve this error by using this.cdRef.detectChanges(); in ngOnInit() but i am not sure if this is the right aproach and it probably slows angular down because it triggers a new check. what do you think?

Comment: @AndreasOwen yes, you can use that approach, here is a good article [change-detection](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)